# Change value of dictionary to other dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

change `dict` to `dict2`

```
dict = {'1':[2,3,4,5]  '2':[3,4,6]}


dict2 = {'1':{2:1,3:1,4:1,5:1}, '2':{3:1,4:1,6:1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dict.fromkeys` method:

```
d = {'1': [2,3,4,5], '2': [3,4,6]}
dict2 = {k: dict.fromkeys(v, 1) for k, v in d.items()}
```

`dict2` becomes:

```
{'1': {2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}, '2': {3: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1}}
```